# Download all Xcode crash reports

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have iOS app with a lot of crashes. When I open Xcode organizer I can see number of crashes [image]

But when I want list all crashes, I can't, because Xcode downloads only few of them. [image]

The Crash is in library (dependency injection), but the cause of the crash is in my App at several places. Xcode merge all crashes of this type in one huge thread. It is actually many different crashes. How can I download all crashes or how can I split the thread?